# Show that $\mathcal L_X g_{ij} = \nabla_i X_j + \nabla_j X_i$

Tags: differential-geometry, ricci-flow

I’m trying to understand equation (1.8) on p. 4 of Chow et al.’s “The Ricci flow: techniques and applications”. There, the authors say that, using indices, the equation

$$ -2\operatorname{Rc}(g) = \epsilon g + \mathcal L_X g$$

becomes

$$ -2R_{ij} = \nabla_i X_j + \nabla_j X_i + \epsilon g_{ij}. \tag{1.8}$$

But how come is $\mathcal L_X g_{ij} = \nabla_i X_j + \nabla_j X_i$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the Lie derivative of the tensor metric $g$ in terms of the Levi-Civita connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172175/how-to-see-the-lie-derivative-of-the-tensor-metric-g-in-terms-of-the-levi-civi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been asked several times (in different phrasings), e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172175/how-to-see-the-lie-derivative-of-the-tensor-metric-g-in-terms-of-the-levi-civi) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4166057/lie-derivative-of-the-metric-tensor).

The best answer in my opinion is this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3189815/1060681

Its from page 14 of [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nsher/ricciflow.pdf](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ensher/ricciflow.pdf).